# Fake array slicing operator: Make it shorter

Tags: php, arrays, operators, slice

Is there some innovative way to make the "print" shorter without too much confusion? And which of the "print" do you like most?

```
define('_','_');
function _j($a, $b) {
    return $a._.$b;
}

// Output 0_0
print (0)._.(0);
print _j(0,0);
```

**Update**

What I want to do is to have slice syntax that are in Python/Ruby into PHP
eg.

```
a[1:3]
a[1,3]
a[1..3]
```

to make it into PHP you need to quote like this `$a["1:3"]` ($a is a class with ArrayAccess interface) so I was thinking if there is some otherways, `$a[(0)._.(0)]` This is too long.

Comment: `$a["1:3"]` will not slice the array in php. there is [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) though

Comment: I updated my post again:P $a is a class with ArrayAccess interface so I can internal make slice inside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you want to do? concatenate strings? use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
echo implode('_', array(0, 0));
```

not shorter, but definitely less confusing, more readable and it best conveys the intention

---

edit now that the question has enough information:

you have a class which implements the ArrayAccess interface.

why not use decimal numbers to achieve your slicing operator?

```
 $a = new PythonArray(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
 $b = $a[1.3];
```

you should then be able to convert the number to a string and split on the period. you could also use `floor` to get both parts. then delegate to `array_slice`:

```
 list($start, $len) = explode('.', (string)$offset);
 return array_slice($internal_array, $start, $len);
```

be aware though, there might be problems with floating point precision.
what's wrong with using quotes though? two extra characters is not too bad.

Comment: I feel that having quote is inconsistent, but maybe it is the best choice. 
Very good idea with decimals!!

Answer (score 6):

If you intend to remove confusion, you really shouldn't be writing such code because it's a step short of obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's PHP, you could make it a tiny bit shorter by using echo instead of print.

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward approach works well.

Compare

```
print "0_0";
print _j(0,0);
```

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest and non confusing way :p

```
echo "0_0";
```